# Check a dataframe against another dataframe and return errors

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame (`df`) which looks like:

```
ID  Location Score
23    London     A
34   Bristol     C
 2   Swansea     D
67    London     A
32      Bath     D
```

I have a validation data-frame called `valid`, which looks like:

```
Main_Location Sub_Location1 Sub_location2
       London       Bristol          Bath
```

I would like to return a data-frame that picks up any rows in `df` (lets call the data-frame `error`) which do not have a location in the `valid` data-frame

So my `error` data-frame would look like:

```
ID  Location Score
  2  Swansea     D
```

As Swansea is not in the `valid` dataframe the row of information is returned to the `error` dataframe.

Have tried to use without success:

```
error = ~df['Location'].isin(valid)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `valid.values.flatten()` to check:

```
error = df[~df.Location.isin(valid.values.flatten())]
```

Returns:

```
   ID Location Score
2   2  Swansea     D
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it is to Transpose with `T` and use its default column name '0'

```
df['Location'].isin(valid.T[0])
```

#### Output

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
```

And use it as your indexer

```
df[~df['Location'].isin(valid.T[0])]

   ID Location Score
2   2  Swansea     D
```